# Changing margins in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Where can I change the margins in my spreadsheet to fit what I want on a single page?? I can do it in excel but when I import to google docs to share, it changes it and it won't print how I need it to.  Will you please put a margins option for spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

No the feature is not available yet for spreadsheet, only for document (File > Page setup).